# docker logs multiple containers

Tags: docker

I have a requirement where data gets loaded into the system using load balanced docker containers. We have multiple images of docker running on different instances either of which picks up the job and load data. The data loading process is reflected in "docker logs -f", but I need to check all the container logs manually and then figure out which container is active and loading data to tail for logs.

Is there a way though which I check which docker is active and tail it for logs. Or may be merge all the container logs into a single and then tail it.
I have good understanding on shell so any pointers would be helpful.

Please let me know if further details needed.
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "which container is active".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use docker compose you should be able to do `docker service logs` to see logs from any container making up a service.

Comment: We do not use swarm. Is there any other alternative.

Comment: Compose is not the same as swarm. There sure are alternatives. You could use another docker loging driver or write a custom loging driver that writes all logs to one file or similar.

Comment: Got following error while running the command against the container.
Error response from daemon: 

This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry I tought its not swarm exclusive. My bad